# How to put lots of brackets

Tags: verbatim, brackets

I want to show all valid bracketed strings made from {} [] (). This is the intended output:

```
{[()]}
{[]()}
{[]}()
{([])}
{()[]}
{()}[]
{}[()]
{}[]()
{}([])
{}()[]
[{()}]
[{}()]
[{}]()
[({})]
[(){}]
[()]{}
[]{()}
[]{}()
[]({})
[](){}
({[]})
({}[])
({})[]
([{}])
([]{})
([]){}
(){[]}
(){}[]
()[{}]
()[]{}
```

This is what I did:

```
\{[()]\}\\
\{[]()\}\\
\{[]\}()\\
\{([])\}\\
\{()[]\}\\
\{()\}[]\\
\{\}[()]\\
\{\}[]()\\
\{\}([])\\
\{\}()[]\\
[\{()\}]\\
[\{\}()]\\
[\{\}]()\\
[(\{\})]\\
[()\{\}]\\
[()]\{\}\\
[]\{()\}\\
[]\{\}()\\
[](\{\})\\
[]()\{\}\\
(\{[]\})\\
(\{\}[])\\
(\{\})[]\\
([\{\}])\\
([]\{\})\\
([])\{\}\\
()\{[]\}\\
()\{\}[]\\
()[\{\}]\\
()[]\{\}\
```

However, some of these cause an error. Any idea why this is happening? What is the best way to go about this?

Edit: Sorry for not putting up an MWE and the full example. This is my old `.tex` file. The ones that are commented are the ones causing an error(!Missing number, treated as zero.    \protect):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   Lots of Brackets:\\
   \texttt{
      \{[()]\}\\
      \{[]()\}\\
      \{[]\}()\\
      \{([])\}\\
      \{()[]\}\\
      \{()\}[]\\
      \{\}[()]\\
      \{\}[]()\\
      \{\}([])\\
      \{\}()[]\\
      %[\{()\}]\\
      %[\{\}()]\\
      %[\{\}]()\\
      %[(\{\})]\\
      %[()\{\}]\\
      %[()]\{\}\\
      %[]\{()\}\\
      %[]\{\}()\\
      %[](\{\})\\
      %[]()\{\}\\
      (\{[]\})\\
      (\{\}[])\\
      (\{\})[]\\
      ([\{\}])\\
      ([]\{\})\\
      ([])\{\}\\
      ()\{[]\}\\
      ()\{\}[]\\
      ()[\{\}]\\
      ()[]\{\}\\
   }
\end{document}
```

Thanks to David Carlisle's answer, I now know the exact problem. This `.tex` file works perfectly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   Lots of Brackets:\\
   \texttt{
      \{[()]\}\\\relax
      \{[]()\}\\\relax
      \{[]\}()\\\relax
      \{([])\}\\\relax
      \{()[]\}\\\relax
      \{()\}[]\\\relax
      \{\}[()]\\\relax
      \{\}[]()\\\relax
      \{\}([])\\\relax
      \{\}()[]\\\relax
      [\{()\}]\\\relax
      [\{\}()]\\\relax
      [\{\}]()\\\relax
      [(\{\})]\\\relax
      [()\{\}]\\\relax
      [()]\{\}\\\relax
      []\{()\}\\\relax
      []\{\}()\\\relax
      [](\{\})\\\relax
      []()\{\}\\\relax
      (\{[]\})\\\relax
      (\{\}[])\\\relax
      (\{\})[]\\\relax
      ([\{\}])\\\relax
      ([]\{\})\\\relax
      ([])\{\}\\\relax
      ()\{[]\}\\\relax
      ()\{\}[]\\\relax
      ()[\{\}]\\\relax
      ()[]\{\}\\\relax
   }
\end{document}
```

However, I ended up putting all these in another file and using the `listings` package and the `\lstinputlisting` command to insert text directly from a file.

Comment: Could you be more specific and edit your questions with the errors you got and for which combination? A fully (non-)working MWE would be appreciate here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If all you want to do is show them, I would use the `verbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
{[()]}
{[]()}
{[]}()
{([])}
{()[]}
{()}[]
{}[()]
{}[]()
{}([])
{}()[]
[{()}]
[{}()]
[{}]()
[({})]
[(){}]
[()]{}
[]{()}
[]{}()
[]({})
[](){}
({[]})
({}[])
({})[]
([{}])
([]{})
([]){}
(){[]}
(){}[]   
()[{}]
()[]{}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Please *always* post complete documents not just fragments, and state the error message in full.

Addding

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
```

you get

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.14 [\{()\}]
             \
```

this is due to the construction

```
\\
[\{...]
```

Which is the same as `\\[\{...]`  That is the command `\\` with optional argument `\{...` The optional argument of `\\` is a *length* like `\\[10pt]` and so `\{` generates an error that it is not a number.

Using

```
\\\relax
```

Would stop LaTeX looking for the optional argument.

Answer (score 4):

#### edited (2017)

- the answer was broken since `xint 1.09c (2013/10/09)`, i.e. a few days after it was initially posted, due to an internal change in `\xintApplyInline\macro{items}` which attempts an expansion of `\macro` with an abstract `##1`, for reasons I have forgotten. The `1.09b` version of `\xintApplyInline` did not. In the code here the macro `\DefineAVANTAPRES` can not be expanded that way. So I add an `\empty` to get the expansion and salvage the code.
- the answer was also broken since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)`, because since then neither `xint` nor `xintfrac` load `xinttools`. The answer thus needed `\usepackage{xinttools}`.

---

Perhaps you want also to *generate* the patterns?

It is possible to use `TeX` macros for that. For technical reasons, which could be circumvented with some additional work, the code below can not handle  `\{` and `\}`, but only plain characters.

> For `N` pairs of opener-closers, the numbers of allowed patterns,
>   divided by `N!`, are  `1`, `2`, `5`, `14`, `42`, `132`, `429`, `1430`,
>   `4862`, `16796`, for, respectively `N=1`, `2`, ... , `10`. This was
>   obtained  (or rather, confirmed...) from running the code below (the
>   second algorithm, presumably faster). These numbers are the  Catalan Numbers
>   `(2N)!/(N!(N+1)!)` arising in many problems of combinatorics. See
>   http://oeis.org/A000108.

One first declares the (arbitrary one character each) open-close pairs with `\DeclareStuff`.

Then the command `\PrintStuff` is given as argument a list of *opening* characters and it will display the complete list of possibilities *preserving the order of the opening characters*. If `N` is the number of such characters, the true total number of patterns would then have to be multiplied by `N!` to account for permutations. For example for six pairs of opener-closer, one finds `132` patterns, thus the true number of possibilities is `132x720`.

The actual generation of patterns is handled by command `\Stuff` which has a completely expandable recursive structure...

Here is the output. Your case corresponds to the second line which has `5` patterns with `3` pairs, hence truly there are `5x3! = 30` solutions. With `4` pairs there are `14x4!=336` solutions; printing them only up to permutations appears a reasonable choice (just the lazy guy who is happy with his algorithm and does not want to add one more layer for permuting everything...)

*Update*: I have inserted below the output and code for another algorithm, which certainly has a more efficient recursion, and is also easier to explain.

> [image: parentheses]

Here is the code. It uses some macro-programming utilities from package [xinttools](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}% for some of its expandable and non expandable utilities to
                 % deal with lists.

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

% This is NON expandable

% can not be used with \{, \}. Only standard characters

\def\DeclareStuff #1%
{%
    \toks@{}%
    \xintAssignArray #1\to\DATA % attention fait un \edef
    \count@ \@ne
    \loop
      \edef\tmp{\DATA{\count@+1}}%
      \expandafter\let\csname FERMEUR\DATA\count@\endcsname\tmp
      \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@
                         \romannumeral-`0\DATA{\count@}}%
      \advance\count@\tw@
    \ifnum\count@<\DATA{0} % \DATA{0} is twice the number of pairs
    \repeat
    \edef\LESOUVREURS {\the\toks@}%           (The list of only the openers)
    \xintApplyInline{\empty\DefineAVANTAPRES}{\LESOUVREURS}%
}%

\def\DefineAVANTAPRES #1%
{%
    \expandafter\def\csname AVANT#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {##1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname APRES#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {##2}%
}%   

\def\AVANT #1#2{\csname AVANT#1\endcsname #2\relax }%
\def\APRES #1#2{\csname APRES#1\endcsname #2\relax }%


% THE WHOLE STUFF NEXT IS COMPLETELY EXPANDABLE

\def\Stuff #1{\expandafter\Stuffa\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}}%

\def\Stuffa #1{\ifnum \xintNthElt{0}{#1}>1
                  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
               \else
                  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
               \fi
               {\xintApplyUnbraced {\Stuffb {#1}}{#1}}
               {\expandafter{\expandafter#1\csname FERMEUR#1\endcsname}}% 
               }%

\def\Stuffb #1#2%
{%
    \expandafter\Stuffc\expandafter
    {\romannumeral-`0\AVANT #2{#1}}%
    {\romannumeral-`0\APRES #2{#1}}#2%
}%

\def\Stuffc #1#2%
{%
   \expandafter\Stuffd\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}%

\def\Stuffd #1#2#3%
{%
    \ifnum\xintLength {#1}>0      % APRES
       \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
       \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\ifnum\xintLength {#2}>0     % AVANT
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
     {\expandafter\xintApplyUnbraced\expandafter
        {\expandafter\Join\expandafter
        {\romannumeral-`0\xintApply {\Autour #3}{\Stuff {#1}}}}{\Stuff {#2}}}%
     {\xintApply {\Autour #3}{\Stuff {#1}}}}%
    {\xintApply {\Apres #3}{\Stuff {#2}}}%
}%

\def\Apres #1{\expandafter\Apresa\csname FERMEUR#1\endcsname #1}%
\def\Apresa #1#2#3{ #3#2#1}% the space to stop the romannumeral, but here
                           % nothing is 

\def\Autour #1{\expandafter\Autoura\csname FERMEUR#1\endcsname #1}%
\def\Autoura #1#2#3{ #2#3#1}%

\def\Join #1#2{\xintApply {\Joinb {#2}}{#1}}
\def\Joinb #1#2{ #1#2}% re-reverses order in joining.


% The list is printed in reverse order of its creation, perhaps
% then the pattern is easier to understand by a human


\def\PrintStuff #1{\noindent
                   \xintListWithSep{\hskip1ex plus 1ex minus.5ex }
                   {\xintRevWithBraces{\Stuff {#1}}}%
                   \begingroup\parfillskip\z@\par\endgroup\medskip}

\DeclareStuff {()[]<>-+?!aAbBcCdDeEfF} 

\ttfamily

\PrintStuff {([} 

\PrintStuff {([<}

\PrintStuff {([<-}

\PrintStuff {([<-?}

\PrintStuff {abcdef}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Here is now the output with the following algorithm: the last pair  can not have anything inside it if the order of openers is to be respected. So, one only needs to generate the pattern for one pair less, and insert the last pair at any legal position, that is at any position to the left of the penultimate opener.

Regarding the code, I will not try to explain; at some point I need to generate, say from a list `abcd` something of the type `{-abcd}{a-bcd}{ab-cd}{abc-d}{abcd-}`; rather than writing a macro (which has to be expandable) for that, I use in some way the available tools from `xint`, this is a trick, it would have been better to write the correct tool (because the method here requires some non-expandable definitions first, which could be avoided).

Contrarily to the previous code, the list of patterns outputs by the `\Stuff` macro has the exact given characters, whereas in the previous one, the closing characters are still represented at the time of printing by macros (for example \FERMEUR[ is ] in disguise). However leaving macros could have some use, as their definitions can be modified. To modify the code here, it would be just a matter of leaving or removing a couple of `\expandafter`'s.

But first the output, which is not in the same order as with the previous algorithm, but perhaps is easier to humanly understand what happens when one adds a new pair of delimiters.

> [image: parentheses]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xinttools}% for some of its expandable and non expandable utilities to
                 % deal with lists.

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

% This is NON expandable

% can not be used with \{, \}. Only standard characters

\def\DeclareStuff #1%
{%
    \toks@{}%
    \xintAssignArray #1\to\DATA % attention fait un \edef
    \count@ \@ne
    \loop
      \edef\tmp{\DATA{\count@+1}}%
      \expandafter\let\csname FERMEUR\DATA\count@\endcsname\tmp
      \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks@
                         \romannumeral-`0\DATA{\count@}}%
      \advance\count@\tw@
    \ifnum\count@<\DATA{0}
    \repeat
    \edef\LESOUVREURS {\the\toks@}%
    %\xintApplyInline{\empty\DefineAVANTAPRES}{\LESOUVREURS}%
    \xintApplyInline{\empty\DefineAVANTAPRES}{#1}% more AVANT-APRES
    % \Stuff variant needs it also for closing characters
}%

\def\DefineAVANTAPRES #1%
{%
    \expandafter\def\csname AVANT#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {##1}%
    \expandafter\def\csname APRES#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {##2}%
% rajouté pour variante:
    \expandafter\def\csname SPLITL#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {{##1#1}{##2}}%
    \expandafter\def\csname SPLITR#1\endcsname ##1#1##2\relax {{##1}{#1##2}}%
}%   

\def\AVANT   #1#2{\csname AVANT#1\endcsname #2\relax }%
\def\APRES   #1#2{\csname APRES#1\endcsname #2\relax }%
\def\SPLITL #1#2{\csname SPLITL#1\endcsname #2\relax }%
\def\SPLITR #1#2{\csname SPLITR#1\endcsname #2\relax }%


% Completely Expandable macros:

\def\Stuff #1{\expandafter\Stuffa\expandafter{\romannumeral-`0#1}}%

\def\Stuffa #1{\expandafter\Stuffb\expandafter 
               {\romannumeral-`0\xintLength{#1}}{#1}}%

\def\Stuffb #1#2{\ifnum #1>1
                  \expandafter\@firstoftwo
               \else
                  \expandafter\@secondoftwo
               \fi
               {\expandafter\Stuffc\expandafter 
                  {\romannumeral-`0\xintNthElt {1}{\xintReverseOrder {#2}}}%
                  {#2}}%
               {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                   #2\csname FERMEUR#2\endcsname}}% 
               }%

\def\Stuffc #1#2% #1 = last character of #2
{%
    \expandafter\Stuffd\expandafter #1\expandafter
    {\romannumeral-`0\AVANT #1{#2}}%
}%

\def\Stuffd #1#2%
{%
    \expandafter\Stuffe
    \romannumeral-`0\xintNthElt {1}{\xintReverseOrder{#2}}%
    {#2}#1%
}%

% ouh c'est compliqué
% SPLITL x transforme aabaubxahaoi en {aabaubx}{ahaoi} mais un seul x
% SPLITR x transforme aabaubxahaoi en {aabaub}{xahaoi} mais un seul x

\def\Stuffe #1#2% en #1, le marqueur ouvrant précédent, en #3 le dernier marqueur
{%
    \expandafter\Stufff\expandafter
    {\romannumeral-`0\xintApply {\SPLITL #1}{\Stuff {#2}}}%
}%

\def\Stufff #1#2%
{%
   \xintApplyUnbraced {\Stuffg #2}{#1}%
}%

% compliqué 

\def\Stuffg #1#2{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                 \Stuffk 
                 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                 #1\csname FERMEUR#1\endcsname #2}%

\def\Stuffk #1#2#3#4%
{%
    \xintApply {\Joinb {#3}}{\xintApply {\Insert #1#2}%
                 {\xintApply {\SPLITRrev {#4}}{#4}}{#4#1#2}}%
}%

\def\SPLITRrev #1#2{\SPLITR #2{#1}}% #1 is a "string", #2 a character

\def\Insert  #1#2#3{\Inserta #1#2#3}%
\def\Inserta #1#2#3#4{ #3#1#2#4}%

\def\Joinb #1#2{ #1#2}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% The list is printed in reverse order of its creation, perhaps
% then the pattern is easier to understand by a human


\def\PrintStuff #1{\noindent
                   \xintListWithSep{\hskip1ex plus 1ex minus.5ex }
                   {\xintRevWithBraces{\Stuff {#1}}}%
                   \begingroup\parfillskip\z@\par\endgroup\medskip}

\DeclareStuff {()[]<>-+?!aAbBcCdDeEfF} 

\ttfamily

\PrintStuff {([}


\PrintStuff {([<}


\PrintStuff {([<-}

\PrintStuff {([<-?}

\PrintStuff {abcdef}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, but for now I prefer to write the code for generating the patterns in another language and then including the output. I can easily automate the whole thing by using the 'listings' package and a Makefile.

Comment: I can not blame you for that ;-) surely doing these things in a true programming language is the correct way.